# Sharing image using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Sharing a image from `UIImageView` using `UIActivityViewController`?

I am trying to share a image using `UIActivityViewController`, but I get error:

```
func shareIMG(){
    let activityItems = [self.imageView.image]
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error message:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIActivityViewController' that
>   accepts an argument list of type '(activityItems: [UIImage?],
>   applicationActivities: nil)'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
let activityItem: [AnyObject] = [self.imageView.image as! AnyObject]

let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

self.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Note** : The above code tested in Xcode 6.3 simulator

Comment: @Mariah Now my xcode8 is not working with swift. Let me check and update you soon.

Comment: @Mariah Whats the problem ?

Comment: No problem anymore!

Comment: Its not working xcode 8 i'm also so tired with that. Any other solution ?

Comment: getting crash MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.'

Answer (score 6):

Just create a button and it's action. And install the button's action like this.

**Note: You have to log in your facebook or twitter by going to setting. Then do like this.**

```
@IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("share")

    let myShare = "My beautiful photo! <3 <3"
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageNameHere")

    let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [(image), myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. Since just passing an Image("yourImage") won't work. You HAVE to convert it to UIImage first using UIImage("yourImage"). Worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift 5

```
   let img  = imageView.image!.pngData()
   let messageStr:String  = "some sharing text"
   let shareItems:Array = [img!, messageStr] as [Any]

   let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.print, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo]

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone {
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let popup: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityViewController)
            popup.present(from: sender.bounds, in: sender, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.any, animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Swift 5

Note: While sharing a image as Data

```
func shareApplication() {
    
    let description = "Hi, I have shared my profile"
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/9iH_CxCOzkVQACme6xpCkgzydzo=/0x0:1323x638/920x613/filters:focal(539x248:749x458):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/69851120/Screenshot_2021_09_10_7.38.39_AM.0.png")
    
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url!) {
        
        // MARK: - URL to Data

        let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
        
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [description, image ?? UIImage()], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you need to unwrap activityItems with a !

Comment: Can you elaborate `a`?