# Sharing image and text to Facebook Messenger with UIActivityViewController failing

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

> **Question**
>
> What changes to the code below must be made to ensure Messenger plays
>   nicely with `UIActivityViewController` and shares both the image and
>   text, or at the very least, the image?

---

**Background**

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share text and images from my app and send them to email, messages and other sharing apps. `UIActivityViewController` is great and works in a simple and standard way with most apps… but, I’m having issues with Messenger (Facebook Messenger) which doesn’t want to cooperate.

In the below code, I tap a `UIButton` which takes a snapshot image of the screen, turns it into a .png, and then sends the prepared image (`imageShare`) along with my prepared text (`textShare`) to the `UIActivityViewController`. This simple method allows my app to successfully share to email, messages and many other sharing apps except Messenger.

(Side note, Facebook is only able to share the prepared image (`imageShare`) but not the text.)

---

**Issues**

These are the problems when trying to share with `UIActivityViewController` to Messenger :

- **When sharing `activityItems: [textShare, imageShare]`**

  - Messenger only sends the shared text.
- **When sharing `activityItems: [textShare]`**

  - The option to share to Messenger is not even available in `UIActivityViewController`.
- **When sharing `activityItems: [imageShare]`**

  - An error is displayed: *“Couldn't Load Content. There was a problem while loading your content. Please try again.”*

---

**Code**

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {

    // Take snapshot of screen
    let imageSnapshot: UIImage!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height), afterScreenUpdates: false)
    imageSnapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Prepare text to share
    let textShare: String!
    textShare = "This is my original text."

    // Prepare image to share
    let imageShare: NSData
    imageShare = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSnapshot)!

    // Share text and image
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textShare, imageShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

---

**Image**

iOS presenting the `UIActivityViewController` with available applications.

[image: UIActivityViewController screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UIImage instead NSData. You can convert UIImage to AnyObject and add to your array.

Also look at this question: [Sharing image using UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955140/sharing-image-using-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I change `NSData` to `UIImage` I get an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'NSData' to type 'UIImage'. Would you be able to expand on your answer showing the code change in context please?

Comment: He's not saying to literally replace the type (next to `imageShare`) `NSData` with `UIImage` but rather to send the `UIImage` instance instead of creating an `NSData` instance from the `UIImage` you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
let textShare = "This is my original text."
var shareObject = [AnyObject]()
if textShare != nil {
    shareObject.append(textShare as AnyObject)
}

let Yourimage = UIImage(named: "image.png")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Yourimage!) as NSData? 

if let data = imageData {
    shareObject.append(data)
}

if shareObject.count > 0 { // check condition for text and image
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareObject, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but this doesn't correct the issue, the image is still missing, only the text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end what was needed was an extra step of converting `NSData` back into `UIImage`.

> Note, the one issue with this approach of converting `NSData` back
>   into `UIImage` is that it produces image quality that is either
>   lossless (i.e. Message and Mail) or lossy (i.e. Notes, Photos,
>   Messenger).
>
> Interestingly Messages, Mail, and a variety of third party sharing
>   apps were quite content sharing the `NSData` in the
>   `UIActivityViewController` whereas Messenger would just not tolerate
>   it. (I'd be interested to understand why exactly?)

---

**The changes**

From this:

```
    // Prepare image to share
    let imageShare: NSData
    imageShare = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSnapshot)!
```

To that:

```
    // Prepare image to share
    let imageShareData: NSData
    imageShareData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSnapshot)!
    let imageShare = UIImage(data: imageShareData)!
```

---

**The final working code**

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {

    // Take snapshot of screen
    var imageSnapshot: UIImage!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height), afterScreenUpdates: false)
    imageSnapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Prepare text to share
    let textShare: String!
    textShare = "This is my original text."

    // Prepare image to share
    let imageShareData: NSData
    imageShareData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSnapshot)!
    let imageShare = UIImage(data: imageShareData)!

    // Share text and image
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textShare, imageShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `UIImage`, you're converting it to `NSData` and then you've converted it back into a `UIImage` without doing anything to it. Just eliminate the unnecessary steps and send the original `UIImage` instance.

Comment: Thanks @shim. The issue is the original UIImage appears to be a lossy jpg when saved. I'm wanting to preserve a crisp screenshot which is why I am converting to png.

Comment: Then why did you ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45153494/1032372)?